# Using multiple methods on one controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, angularjs-scope, asp.net-core-1.0

Please I need some help and advice. I want to use two methods on one controller. The first method is to display selected rooms and the second is to display the selected pax. However, only the first method works, the second md-select don't display the array in the second method. Here is my js and html code snippet:

```js
var app = angular.module('CoreWebApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'ngAnimate']);

app.controller('SelectedTextController', function($scope) {
  $scope.rooms = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
  $scope.selectedRoom;
  $scope.getSelectedText = function() {
    if ($scope.selectedRoom !== undefined) {
      return $scope.selectedRoom + " Room(s)";
    } else {
      return "Rooms";
    }
  };

  $scope.paxes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  $scope.selectedPax;
  $scope.getSelectedPersons = function() {
    if ($scope.selectedPax !== undefined) {
      return $scope.selectedPax;
    } else {
      return "Pax";
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Rooms</label>
  <div layout-sm="column" layout-align="center end">
    <md-select md-no-resize ng-model="selectedRoom" md-selected-text="getSelectedText()">
      <md-optgroup label="rooms">
        <md-option ng-value="room" ng-repeat="room in rooms">{{room}} Rooms</md-option>
      </md-optgroup>
    </md-select>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <label>Pax</label>
  <div>
    <md-select ng-model="selectedPax" md-selected-text="getSelectedPersons()" aria-label="">
      <md-optgroup label="pax">
        <md-option ng-value="pax" ng-repeat="pax in paxes">{{pax}}</md-option>
      </md-optgroup>
    </md-select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot run your code to test but I believe the following

```
<md-optgroup label="pax">
```

should be

```
<md-optgroup label="paxes">
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question you should define your angular app and controller to the main div

```js
var app = angular.module('CoreWebApp', []);

app.controller('SelectedTextController', function($scope) {
  $scope.rooms = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
  $scope.selectedRoom;
  
  $scope.getSelectedText = function() {
    if ($scope.selectedRoom !== undefined) {
      return $scope.selectedRoom + " Room(s)";
    } else {
      return "Rooms";
    }
  };

  $scope.paxes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  $scope.selectedPax;
  
  $scope.getSelectedPersons = function() {
    if ($scope.selectedPax !== undefined) {
      return $scope.selectedPax;
    } else {
      return "Pax";
    }
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="CoreWebApp" ng-controller="SelectedTextController">

<div >
  <label>Rooms</label>
  <div layout-sm="column" layout-align="center end">
    <md-select md-no-resize ng-model="selectedRoom" md-selected-text="getSelectedText()">
      <md-optgroup label="rooms">
        <md-option ng-value="room" ng-repeat="room in rooms">{{room}} Rooms</md-option>
      </md-optgroup>
    </md-select>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <label>Pax</label>
  <div>
    <md-select ng-model="selectedPax" md-selected-text="getSelectedPersons()" aria-label="">
      <md-optgroup label="pax">
        <md-option ng-value="pax" ng-repeat="pax in paxes">{{pax}}</md-option>
      </md-optgroup>
    </md-select>
  </div>
</div>
  
  </div>
```

Comment: i put my ng-app to the html tag, and the controller in the div containing the md-selects but still the second method doesn't works

Comment: In your if condition on second method you have use !== instead of this use != and check

Comment: what's the difference between` !==` and `!=` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine.  You didn't post your entire code so I can't tell.  Just make sure you have ng-controller and ng-app attributes in the HTML.

Here's your code with ng-controller and ng-app.  Also, make sure all necessary js and css libs are included.

https://plnkr.co/edit/7gpRPGnF4Tr8oIxrUsmV?p=preview

```
<body ng-app="CoreWebApp" ng-controller="SelectedTextController">
<div>
  <label>Rooms</label>
  <div layout-sm="column" layout-align="center end">
    <md-select md-no-resize="" ng-model="selectedRoom" md-selected-text="getSelectedText()">
      <md-optgroup label="rooms">
        <md-option ng-value="room" ng-repeat="room in rooms">{{room}} Rooms</md-option>
      </md-optgroup>
    </md-select>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Pax</label>
  <div>
    <md-select ng-model="selectedPax" md-selected-text="getSelectedPersons()" aria-label="">
      <md-optgroup label="pax">
        <md-option ng-value="pax" ng-repeat="pax in paxes">{{pax}}</md-option>
      </md-optgroup>
    </md-select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I followed your advise, but still it doesn't work :(

Comment: You saw that the plunkr working right?  Post more code as there might be a small typo or mistake that prevents your code from working.